# Inner measure (inner set function) on functional closed sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling with the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{Z}:=\{Z\subseteq X \,\big|\,\exists\,\psi\in\mathcal{C}(X)\,:\,Z=\psi^{-1}(\{0\})\}$ the family of functional closed sets in $X$. Assume that $L$ is a nonnegative functional (i.e., nonnegative on nonnegative functions) on $\mathcal{C}_b(X)$, the set of all bounded real valued functions on $X$. Define the set function $m$ on $\mathcal{Z}$ by
>   $$m(Z)=\inf\{L(f)\,\big|\,f\in\mathcal{C}_b(X), \mathbb{1}_Z\leq f\leq 1\}$$
>   and denote by $m_*$ the inner set function 
>   $$m_*(Z):=\sup\{m(Z')\,\big|\,Z'\subseteq Z,Z'\in\mathcal{Z}\}.$$
>   Show that for all $Z\in\mathcal{Z}$ one has $m(Z)=m_*(Z)$.

The textbook I'm following (V.I.Bogachev, Measure Theory 2) states that it's easy to see that $m(Z)=m_*(Z)$ for all $Z\in\mathcal{Z}$ from the fact that $\mathcal{Z}$ is closed with respect to finite unions, which I have already proven. I don't really see why this is needed here. In my opinion, since $L$ is nonnegative, $m$ is monotone (i.e.,$Z_1$, $Z_2\in\mathcal{Z}$, $Z_1\subseteq Z_2\,\Rightarrow\,m(Z_1)\leq m(Z_2)$), so it seems natural that $\sup\{m(Z')\,\big|\,Z'\subseteq Z,Z'\in\mathcal{Z}\}=m(Z)$. But the past has shown that whenever Mr. Bogachev and me are not the same opinion, it turns out that he's right and I'm wrong, so I wonder what I'm missing here :)

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you very much in advance for your efforts!

Greetings,
Florian

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything here. Monotonicity of $m$ is clearly enough here and that doesn't need closure of $\mathcal{Z}$ under finite unions although it may later be needed to show that $m_{\star}$ indeed define a measure on $\mathfrak{A}(X)$.